# Davinci Resolve 17: How do you export individual clips with timeline audio and effect changes?

Tags: davinci-resolve, export

Is there a way for me to export "individual clips" with their timeline changes?

I am new to resolve and am trying to export "individual clips" with their effects and audio edits mixed in.

When I export "individual clips", the clip is unedited and none of the effects and audio changes are saved. In addition, the audio is not mixed down. E.g. I delete track 2 of the clip and export,  the rendered clip still has multiple tracks and the deleted track can still be heard. Also, if I have a zoom in, the exported clip doesn't have the effect.

I currently have to mark in and out each and every clip individually and export as a "single clip" in order for these changes to be affected. This means I cannot use many of the "individual clips" features like automatic sequential naming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think setting an *In-* and *Outpoint* would do the trick. Essentially you are cropping down the timeline to the time between In- and Outpoint. When on the Edit tab, you set the Inpoint by pressing I and the Outpoint with O. Then you can just export the entire video, which will be cropped down with color grading, music etc. applied. You can of course choose where to place the points freely and include several clips following each other.

Don't forget to remove the In- and Outpoints afterwards by pressing Alt/Option + X in the Edit tab. These points cause weird behavior sometimes.

Comment: This solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Copy your timeline and paste it at the end of the timeline. Select this cloned timeline and convert it to compound clip. Move that compound clip above your original timeline. Then use the arrow keys up or down to jump to each cut and press C. Do this to match every cut for the clips you want to have individualized, then move this new sequence to a new timeline